# Displaying PDF with correct format

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a PDF data that coming from a 3th party service starts with this:

```
%PDF-1.3 %���� 5 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /LastModified (D:20220519105837+02'00') /Resources 2 0 R /MediaBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /CropBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /BleedBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /TrimBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /ArtBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /Contents 6 0 R /Rotate 0 /Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> /PZ 1 >> endobj 6 0 obj <> stream x�3�357�r/ �R��R)@���\N! �n�
```

and I would like to provide this PDF data to my visitors via a web page. Currently, I am setting `application/pdf; charset=UTF-8` and `CONTENT_DISPOSITION` as inline on my response with this data.

But I am getting a blank PDF layout page on my webpage. Like that:

[image]

Do you know how can I show this PDF data on browser correctly?

Comment: At first glance it looks like you have somewhere treated the PDFs as textual data (handling them using character strings or arrays). PDFs are binary data, and handling them as character data has the risk of damaging them. The replacement characters '�' in your example point that way, and your use of 'charset=UTF-8' also does.

Comment: yes, it makes sense. I need to process it as bytes. Your comment helped me so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special thanks to @mkl
It seems I need to evaluate 3rd party service response as byte. Then I convert it to base64 and decode it to string with charset ISO-8859-1.

Lastly, I put this string on HTML with `application/pdf; charset=ISO-8859-1` content type.